# Ideas for cleaner solution to an issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

I'm not sure if this question is for here, so if it's not, please excuse me, I will delete it.

I'm using Symfony2, Twig and Doctrine. I'm working on a ToDo App as an excercise and the web page looks like this:

```
Today (5 tasks)
- Work (2 tasks)
  - clean the desk
  - write report
- Home (3 task)
  - Pay (2 tasks)
    - Internet
    - Electricity
  - Buy (1 task)
    - Eggs

Completed (1 task)
- Work 
  - Talk to boss
```

I have categories (Work and Home), subcategories (Pay and Buy) and tasks with status (completed or not)

My problem is to count the remaining tasks.

Because the number is shown before the tasks, in order to know it I do something like this:

```
 for each main_category
   if the main_category has subcateries 
     count = 0
     for each subcategory
       for each task of the subcategory if the task.status is 0 (uncompleted)
         set count = count + 1
       endfor
     endfor
   else
     count = 0
     for each task of the category if the task.status is 0
       set count = count + 1
     endfor 
   endif
 endfor
```

(I'm not even sure it works, but I think you got the idea.)

I think that this is complecated and slow to check this each time the page refreshes.

The other option I can think of is to add a new field to the Category Entity (number of uncompleted tasks or maybe I will need both - number of completed and uncompleted). But then each time I change the status of the task I should change the number, too.

To be honest, I have to idea which will be faster and which will be better (so I'm asking this question), but the first one seems really complecated and difficult to understand to me.

Can you plese tell me if you have any better ideas how to achieve this functionality, or if you have not - which of the ways is better, which will be faster and so on. I really wan tto learn to write code of good quality. :)

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I am assuming you are using oneToMany relations on the entities?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention. Categories and subcategories have OneToMany relation (self referencing) - because subcategories are categories, too. Category and Tasks have OneToMany, too.

Comment: Not sure what you really want to do. To count the incomplete tasks is easy. What is your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/using-views-with-doctrine.html) is something that might help. The idea is to create a view for a category which would have the added count of tasks. So, you could create a view which would return the needed data with the notification counts included in the result. Remember to add the number of nested tasks (from the subcategories) as well. Querying the views can work a bit slower than the usual tables, but I think it would still be faster than many iterations. You will move some of the execution time to the SQL server as well, which can be a good thing to do.